# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=e^{\theta x}$. Show that $E[f(X)]=exp(\lambda (e^\theta -1))$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, riemann-sum

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=e^{\theta x}$, where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $X ~ Po(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda >0$. Show that $E[f(X)]=exp(\lambda (e^\theta -1))$.

---

By theorem, $E[f(x)]=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{f(x)P(X=x)}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{e^{\theta x}(\frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}})=e^{\theta-\lambda}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^x\lambda^x}{x!}=e^{\theta-\lambda}(\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}e^x)(\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!})=e^{\theta-\lambda}(e^\lambda)(\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}e^x)=e^{\theta}(\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}e^x)$

First question, is my calculation correct? Second question, what is the infinite sum of $e^x$

Comment: The third equality is wrong: $e^{\theta x} \neq e^\theta e^x$. (Which brings to the relevant second question: for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^k = \infty$, hinting that your result is wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum should start at $0$, and the third equality you have is wrong. Recall that
$
e^ae^b = e^{a+b}
$ (*not* $e^ae^b = e^{ab}$); and that $e^{ab} = (e^a)^b$. 
 Using this, you have $$
\mathbb{E}[f(x)]=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{f(k)\mathbb{P}\{ X=k \}} = 
e^{-\lambda}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{e^{\theta k} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}} = 
e^{-\lambda}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(e^\theta\lambda)^k}{k!}}
= e^{-\lambda}e^{e^\theta\lambda} = e^{(e^\theta-1)\lambda}
$$
proving the result. (The last steps use the fact that $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^k}{k!}} = e^x$.)